# Get a nested property of a complex object at any level of depth

Tags: javascript, performance, depth-first-search

Given a complex object (with nested objects at any depth) I need to be able to quickly retrieve a value for a given property `name`.

I have designed the following code, I would like to know:

- How to tune my code for maximum performance considering passing a big object?
- Am I missing some case in `data.a.x`?
- Any other improvements?

```js
var data = {
  a: {
    a1: 'hello',
    a2: true,
    a3: false,
    a4: {},
    a5: [],
    a6: ['red', 'blue', true],
    a7: null,
    a8: undefined,
    a9: NaN,
    a10: function() {},
    a11: Math,
    a12: JSON,
    a13: /a-z/,
    a14: new ReferenceError,
    a15: new Date,
    a16: new Number(7),
    a17: new String("abc"),
    a18: new Boolean(true)
  },
  b: {
    b1: {
      b1a: true,
      b1b: 100
    },
    b2: {
      b2a: true,
      b2b: false,
      b2c: 10.10
    }
  }
}

var app = {
  findProperty: function(data, name) {
    var toType = function(obj) {
      return ({}).toString.call(obj).match(/\s([a-zA-Z]+)/)[1].toLowerCase()
    };
    var data = data,
      process = true,
      result = {
        isFound: false,
        value: null
      };
    var recursion = function(data, name) {
      var type = toType(data);
      if (type === 'object') {
        Object.keys(data).forEach(function(property) {
          if (process) {
            if (name in data) {
              process = false;
              result.isFound = true;
              result.value = data[name];
            } else if (typeof data[property] === 'object') {
              recursion(data[property], name);
            }
          }
        });
      }
    };
    recursion(data, name);
    return result;
  }
}

console.clear();
// found
var a1 = app.findProperty(data, 'a1');
console.log('a1', a1.isFound, a1.value);

var a2 = app.findProperty(data, 'a2');
console.log('a2', a2.isFound, a2.value);

var a3 = app.findProperty(data, 'a3');
console.log('a3', a3.isFound, a3.value);

var a4 = app.findProperty(data, 'a4');
console.log('a4', a4.isFound, a4.value);

var a5 = app.findProperty(data, 'a5');
console.log('a5', a5.isFound, a5.value);

var a6 = app.findProperty(data, 'a6');
console.log('a6', a6.isFound, a6.value);

var a7 = app.findProperty(data, 'a7');
console.log('a7', a7.isFound, a7.value);

var a8 = app.findProperty(data, 'a8');
console.log('a8', a8.isFound, a8.value);

var a9 = app.findProperty(data, 'a9');
console.log('a9', a9.isFound, a9.value);

var a10 = app.findProperty(data, 'a10');
console.log('a10', a10.isFound, a10.value);

var a11 = app.findProperty(data, 'a11');
console.log('a11', a11.isFound, a11.value);

var a12 = app.findProperty(data, 'a12');
console.log('a12', a12.isFound, a12.value);

var a13 = app.findProperty(data, 'a13');
console.log('a13', a13.isFound, a13.value);

var a14 = app.findProperty(data, 'a14');
console.log('a14', a14.isFound, a14.value);

var a15 = app.findProperty(data, 'a15');
console.log('a15', a15.isFound, a15.value);

var a16 = app.findProperty(data, 'a16');
console.log('a16', a16.isFound, a16.value);

var a17 = app.findProperty(data, 'a17');
console.log('a17', a17.isFound, a17.value);

var a18 = app.findProperty(data, 'a18');
console.log('a18', a18.isFound, a18.value);


var b = app.findProperty(data, 'b');
console.log('b', b.isFound, b.value);

var b1 = app.findProperty(data, 'b1');
console.log('b1', b1.isFound, b1.value);

var b2 = app.findProperty(data, 'b2');
console.log('b2', b2.isFound, b2.value);

var b1a = app.findProperty(data, 'b1a');
console.log('b1a', b1a.isFound, b1a.value);

var b1b = app.findProperty(data, 'b1b');
console.log('b1b', b1b.isFound, b1b.value);

var b2a = app.findProperty(data, 'b2a');
console.log('b2a', b2a.isFound, b2a.value);

var b2b = app.findProperty(data, 'b2b');
console.log('b2b', b2b.isFound, b2b.value);

// not found
var xxx = app.findProperty(data, 'xxx');
console.log('xxx', xxx.isFound, xxx.value);

var yyy = app.findProperty(data, 'yyy');
console.log('yyy', yyy.isFound, yyy.value);
```

[toTry function reference](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/08/08/fixing-the-javascript-typeof-operator)

Comment: Could you provide a more realistic use case?

Comment: How big is... big? And does it always follow this structure where subsequent keys have the same prefix?

Comment: @200_success thanks for commenting, regarding the realistic use case.. in my case, it is a complex set of business rules defined in a JS object (crated by parsing a JSON). The script is used extensively in the app.

Comment: @Sumurai8 no the prefix could be arbitrarily name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the `JSON.stringify`'s `replacer` argument.
This way it becomes much more simple:

```
var app =
  findProperty: function(data, name) {
    var result = {
      isFound: false,
      value: null
    };
    JSON.stringify(data, function(k, v) {
      if (k == name) {
        result.isFound = true;
        result.value = v;
        return undefined; // stop stringification
      } else {
        return v; // continue with same value
      }
    });
    return result;
  }
}
```

Compared to your original function, there are two points to consider:

- one little caveat is that a `Date` object is returned stringified, e.g. for `a15` in your `data`example:

  - has an original value of `new Date`.
  - is returned as `Date {Thu Jan 14 2016 18:34:10 GMT+0100}` by your function.
  - is returned as `2016-01-14T17:34:10.220Z` by the mine.
- your function excludes `Array` objects, while the mine processes them, e.g. calling `app.findProperty(data, '0')` will return `red` (from `a6: ['red', 'blue', true]` in your `data`example).

My version seems to be faster (approximatively x2) using your `data` example, but it's not certain how it'll be in any case.

The snippet below tries to illustrate it, simultaneously controlling the results between the two versions:

```js
var data = {
  a: {
    a1: 'hello',
    a2: true,
    a3: false,
    a4: {},
    a5: [],
    a6: ['red', 'blue', true],
    a61: {a61a: 'red', a61b: 'blue'},
    a7: null,
    a8: undefined,
    a9: NaN,
    a10: function() {},
    a11: Math,
    a12: JSON,
    a13: /a-z/,
    a14: new ReferenceError,
    a15: new Date,
    a16: new Number(7),
    a17: new String("abc"),
    a18: new Boolean(true)
  },
  b: {
    b1: {
      b1a: true,
      b1b: 100
    },
    b2: {
      b2a: true,
      b2b: false,
      b2c: 10.10
    }
  }
}

var app = {
  findProperty: function(data, name) {
    var toType = function(obj) {
      return ({}).toString.call(obj).match(/\s([a-zA-Z]+)/)[1].toLowerCase()
    };
    var data = data,
      process = true,
      result = {
        isFound: false,
        value: null
      };
    var recursion = function(data, name) {
      var type = toType(data);
      if (type === 'object') {
        Object.keys(data).forEach(function(property) {
          if (process) {
            if (name in data) {
              process = false;
              result.isFound = true;
              result.value = data[name];
            } else if (typeof data[property] === 'object') {
              recursion(data[property], name);
            }
          }
        });
      }
    };
    recursion(data, name);
    return result;
  },

  findProp: function(data, name) {
    var result = {
      isFound: false,
      value: null
    };
    JSON.stringify(data, function(k, v) {
      if (k == name) {
        result.isFound = true;
        result.value = v;
        return undefined; // stop stringification
      } else {
        return v; // continue with same value
      }
    });
    return result;
  }
}

var names = [
  'a', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6', 'a61', 'a61a', 'a7', 'a8', 'a9',
  'a10', 'a11', 'a12', 'a13', 'a14', 'a15', 'a16', 'a17', 'a18',
  'b', 'b1', 'b2', 'b1a', 'b1b', 'b2a', 'b2b', 'b2c', 'xxx', 'yyy'
];
var results = {};

function exec(func) {
  results[func] = [];
  begTime = Date.now();
  for (var i = 0, n = names.length; i < n; i++) {
    var name = names[i],
        result = app[func](data, name);
    results[func][i] = result.value;
    console.log(name, result.isFound, result.value);
  }
  console.log(
    '--- using ', func + ':', (Date.now() - begTime) + 'ms');
}

console.clear();
exec('findProperty');
exec('findProp');
for (var i = 0, n = results.findProperty.length; i < n; i++) {
  if (results.findProperty[i] !== results.findProp[i]) {
    console.log(
      '*** Error in ' + i + ':',
      results.findProperty[i], '<-->', results.findProp[i]
    );
  }
}
```

Apart from the already mentioned `Date` difference, you'll see an "error" on the `NaN` value: this is normal since `NaN` is equal to nothing, even itself.

Comment: Thanks for your insight I found it very interesting and useful!

Comment: just a reference note: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: @GibboK Glad to help. Regarding your second comment, I wonder if you want me to point some  peculiar point? (maybe your "just a reference note" means you put it merely in order to further readers have it available, but English is not my mother language so I'm not sure).

Comment: I think reference to replacer  on mozilla it is pretty good so all fine as it is for me :), once again thanks for commenting and your time on this :)

Answer (score 1):

There is one opportunity I can see to make it a little more performing than it is currently. Below is my implementation of the app.findProperty function. It is checking for the if name in data outside of the Object.keys(data) for each loop.

The reason being, the if condition `if (name in data)` is not dependent on the looping variable `property` in the Object.keys(data) for each loop and hence it would evaluate to be the same no matter how many times it is evaluated. That evaluation with in the `Object.keys(data)` for each loop would evaluate it multiple times causing the code to run slower. Also if your property "name" is available in the data, and your `if (name in data)` evaluates to true, there is no need to even enumerate the object's keys at that level.

```
var app = {
  findProperty: function(data, name) {
    var toType = function(obj) {
      return ({}).toString.call(obj).match(/\s([a-zA-Z]+)/)[1].toLowerCase()
    };
    var data = data,
      process = true,
      result = {
        isFound: false,
        value: null
      };
    var recursion = function(data, name) {
      var type = toType(data);
      if (type === 'object') {
        if (name in data) {
            process = false;
            result.isFound = true;
            result.value = data[name];
            return result;
        }
        Object.keys(data).forEach(function(property) {
          if (process) {
            if (typeof data[property] === 'object') {
              recursion(data[property], name);
            }
          }
        });
      }
    };
    recursion(data, name);
    return result;
  }
}
```

While this is a good academic project, for learning, there are several real world cases that the code doesn't handle like what if the property is occurring multiple times in different objects at different depths. How would you be able to query where a specific property a.b.b1.b1b exists no matter b1b is a property defined at several levels. For a more holistic solution for querying JSON, there is a good npm package called [json-query](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-query).